# wordpress plugin adding files to plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am converting some calendar program we have into a wp plugin and am having issues adding files to other php pages.
My code right now is this

```
$the_file="ac-config.inc.php";
if(!file_exists($the_file)) die("<b>".$the_file."</b> not found");
else require_once($the_file);
```

But because everything is now in a plugin it can't find it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `the_file` with `$the_file`

Comment: That file is in the folder of the plugin? or when you call the function of the plugin?

Comment: Please read the php documentation to learn about how and where the engine attempts to find files.

Comment: Sorry it does have      $the_file